# 403 error on translate api v2

Tags: google-api, google-translate

A 403 error on google translate v2

curl "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=mykey&source=en&target=fr&q=please"

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}

in Android

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?" +
            "key=xxxx&target=fr&q=please");
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
           ...
        -> 403
```

I have enabled billing, paid 10$ just to be sure, created a public key with the SHA1 of my android app, turned on the translate API on the console, ...

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Well, have you done what the error says? Is the translate api activated for your project and do you have valid keys configured in your project?

Comment: @Serv Yes, I have enabled billing, paid 10$ just to be sure, created a public key with the SHA1 of my android app, turned on the translate API on the console, ...